# ActiveMQ Artemis lost connections between nodes

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster with 3 live and 3 backup nodes.

[image: topology on node 1]
[image: cluster info]

When 1st live node is overloaded it becomes unstable, and then when load comes down some nodes in cluster don't see all nodes. For example, live node 3 see onlys live node 1. (backup 2 - live 1 in one host, live 3 - backup 1 in one host ), but live node 1 and live node 2 see all nodes in the cluster! If I restart live node 2 - node 3 can see it.
[image: topology on node 3]
[image: cluster info node 3]

Is there some parameter for initiate reconnection between nodes?

If I restart live node 2 - node 3 can see it.

`broker.xml`:

```xml
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://live1:61616</connector>
         <!-- connector to the server1 -->
         <connector name="server1-connector">tcp://live2:61616</connector>
      </connectors>
    
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="smx-art-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>server1-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

Comment: What's your `cluster-connection` configuration in `broker.xml`?

Comment: Write in previous post. My net is not provide multycast, all nodes connects manually live1->live2->live3->live1